# get specefic parts from a log file

Tags: python

I have this file as input:

```
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3 contains message
[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
[0010] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
this is line 6
this is line 7 contains message 2
[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
this is line 9
this is line 10 contains message
[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
[0010] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
[0020] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
this is line 14
this is line 15
[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 F1 : 4F 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
this is line 17 contains message2
[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 F1 : 4F 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 F1 : 4F 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54
```

and I want as output to get only the lines in bytes format just after the line containing the variable "message" for exemple:

```
list1=['[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54','[0010] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 
54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54']

list2= ['[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54',
'[0010] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54','[0020] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 54 : 
41 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54'] 

list3=['[0000] 20 20 20 2A 54 43 54 F1 : 4F 41 4C 20 20 54 54 54']
```

to decode them after separetly.

I have started a small code that detects the line that contains "message" and gets the lines just  after this line and break when the len of the first element of these lines different from 6 but i get at the end a list that contains all the lines decoded with bytes instead I want them in separate lists. Can anyone help me?
Thank you in advance
This a part of the code:

```
def analyse_file(self,file_name):
    list=[]
    input_file = open(file_name, 'r', encoding = "latin-1")
    file_lines = input_file.readlines()
    for i in range(len(file_lines)):
        if ("message" in file_lines[i]):
            x=i
            for j in range (x+1,len(file_lines)):
                m= file_lines[j].split() 
                if (len(m[0])==6):#len([0000]]
                    byte_line=log_file_lines[j]
                    list.append(byte_line)
                 else:
                     break
    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making it harder than it needs to be.  If the line starts with '[', then collect it.  If it doesn't start with '[', then save your collection and start a new one.

```
def analyse_file(self,file_name):
    lists = []
    chunk = []
    keep = False
    for line in open(file_name, 'r', encoding = "latin-1"):
        if "contains message" in line:
            keep = True
        elif line[0] == '[' and keep:
            chunk.append( line )
        elif chunk:
            lists.append(chunk)
            keep = False
            chunk = []
    return lists
```

Comment: I edited the file to show that i can't the lines that starts with '[' because the file contains a lot of them for other messages

Comment: So you use a flag to mark that you saw a "contains message" string.

Comment: this code gives me only the first line after the line that contains "contains message" in only one list.

Comment: Bah, you're right.  I thought I had a cute optimization.  This should be better.